# Licensing for assets in a game but it is free for commercial use

Tags: assets, legal, licensing, commercial, asset-creation

In my game, there is this music that I use and of course before releasing anything for commercial use, I have to have a license for what I dont create for my game for example ( game engine, music, fonts and etc ) some of them are free to use even for commercial purposes.

**My question is** do I need license for it even though it is free for commercial use? and if there is no license for it at all, what should I do to avoid copyrights and legal issues?

Comment: will a screenshot of the website saying that is free for commercial use do? or do I have to contact the actual creator for a license which is pretty much impossible?

Comment: It sounds like that statement IS the licence. Again, to be sure, it would be best if you post the actual content of the statement here so we can ensure there's no miscommunication.

Comment: okay let me try to get it, im using my phone atm and the website is a bit weird in my phone.

Comment: You actually don't have to have a license. Some has first call you out for using a non licensed product or under the wrong conditions like commercial use. So just make a Screenshot of everything royalty free you use or whatever. And keep that. If course can the owner later then claim that it was a rip off and Bla Bla but that is always possible with free stuff. That's why bigger studios rarely use free stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of "free to use even for commercial purposes", it sounds like it already has a license. In this case, one that indicates you can use it for commercial purposes. Conversely, how do you know it can be used in that manner if there wasn't a license saying so?

Most licenses I'm familiar with persist in the sense that they apply to the work in question after you've used. For instance, if it's already free for commercial use, it typically stays that way - your use can't restrict others from using it. Furthermore, many licenses include some language indicating that they must explicitly accompany the work. So if you're using a piece of music with a free for commercial use license, you often must include a copy of the license either directly in the game (as a start up splash screen or an always accessible credits screen) &/or as an accompanying text file.

However, situations & licenses vary, so as indicated in the comments, you should need to post the actual terms of use for the asset in question to ensure we're talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a license along with the music. Unless it is explicitly public domain, you still need to keep whatever licensing they had on it. If there is no license for it, contact the creator of the song (or asset) about their work and they will normally tell you the copyright license they have on it and whether or not you can use it.